# Suppress the log file lines written by a specific package?

Tags: marginpar, logging

The [`marginfix`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginfix) package is *incredibly* verbose in what it writes to the log file. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
Here is some text\marginpar{This is a marginpar}
\end{document}
```

This file includes the following stuff written by `marginfix`:

```
MFX: dumpmargins 
MFX:
addmarginpar (running insert) \bx@A /\bx@B at 1:10.0pt, marginlist=macro:->

MFX:
addmarginpar (exit): marginlist=macro:->\mfx@margin@note \bx@A \bx@B {1.60004pt}\mfx@margin@skip {5.0pt} 
MFX: buildmargin: marginheight=550.0pt 
MFX: buildmargin@down: ENTRY 
MFX:
marginlist=macro:->\mfx@margin@note \bx@A \bx@B {1.60004pt}\mfx@margin@skip {5.
0pt} 
MFX: note@down: ENTRY: \bx@A /\bx@B  at 1.60004pt 
MFX: note@down: adding compressible 1.60004pt 
MFX: margin on right 
MFX: whichbox: \bx@B  
MFX: note@down: adding \bx@B ht 6.94444ptdp 13.94444pt 
MFX: note@down: RETURN space=20.88889pt, pos=22.48892pt 
MFX: skip@down 5.0pt 
MFX: buildmargin@down: RETURN 
MFX: marginlist=macro:-> 
MFX: buildmargin@up: excess=-522.51108pt 
MFX:
marginout=macro:->\mfx@margin@skip {5.0pt}\mfx@margin@note \bx@B \@cons \@freelist \bx@A \@cons \@freelist \bx@B \mfx@margin@compressible {1.60004pt} 
MFX: skip@gobble@up: 5.0pt 
MFX: note@up: \bx@B  
MFX: compressible@up: 1.60004pt, excess=-527.51108pt 
MFX: skip@up: \dimen@  
MFX: attachmargin 
MFX: margin on right
```

Once you have several marginpars floating around this ends up as a whole lot of log file junk you have to wade through.

So: can I turn off allowing marginfix to write to the log file? (either through some secret marginfix option that isn't in the manual or through some general LaTeX method to "mute" certain packages from the log file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that is a error in the .ins-file which has been used to unpack the .dtx. The code you are seeing is meant for debugging.

Get marginfix.dtx and marginfix.ins from CTAN, remove the debug option in marginfix.ins and then run marginfix.ins. This will give you a sainer marginfix.sty. And notify the author.

Comment: This was from the TDS packaged version.

Comment: If the TDS version used the .ins from CTAN this is not surprising. The author made an error and uploaded the debug version. That happens.

Comment: I've notified the author

Answer (score 9):

In general, you can use the [`silence`](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) package which is capable of suppressing warnings and errors of entire packages.

Load the package and write for example

```
\WarningsOff[marginfix]
```

Comment: I like this answer. Unfortunately, it seems it doesn't work in the case of `marginfix` might this be because it is not using "warnings" but some other method to write to the log file?