# marginfix debug mode

Tags: marginpar

I am using the marginpar command with the package marginfix. The package is very chatty and clutters the console when LaTeX runs. The author (Stephen Hicks) anticipated that some people might not like it and provided a no-debug option. This is done when compiling the sty file out of the ins and dtx files and not an run-time option. The version that is packaged with TeXLive 2011 has debug on. I fixed it for myself, but is there a recommended practice? Contact the author, contact someone at CTAN, fix it for yourself and keep quiet? Or is debug supposed to be on?

Comment: [Related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24250/suppress-the-log-file-lines-written-by-a-specific-package) I have emailed the author, but received no reply.

Comment: I think this is one for the package author. There is an `.ins` file on CTAN, which will have been used by TeX Live and MiKTeX to unpack the code from the `.dtx`. The `.ins` has the `debug` option enabled, so the code is unpacked in debug mode. Only the maintainer can (usually) fix the CTAN release, so it'd down to him.

Comment: @Seamus How long ago? We could ask Robin Fairbairns to fix this at CTAN if the author is not contactable.

Comment: @JosephWright Well, Ulrike Fischer answered my question on 27 July, so I emailed a couple of days after that, maybe...

Comment: @Seamus Message sent to Robin.

Comment: In the meanwhile you could say `\makeatletter\let\MFX@debug\@gobble\makeatother` after loading **marginfix**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the following code as `xmarginfix.sty` and call

```
\usepackage[<options>]{xmarginfix}
```

instead of `\usepackage[<options>]{marginfix}`. The only option to **marginfix** is `ypos` that is honored by **xmarginfix**, which has also `debug` and `nodebug` (the default, that disables the messages from **marginfix**).

```
\ProvidesPackage{xmarginfix}
\DeclareOption{debug}{\let\XMF@debug\@empty}
\DeclareOption{nodebug}{\let\XMF@debug\relax}
\DeclareOption{ypos}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{marginfix}}
\ExecuteOptions{nodebug}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\edef\XMF@ecl{\number\errorcontextlines}
\def\XMF@debug{\@ifstar\@gobble\@gobble}
\RequirePackage{marginfix}
\@ifundefined{XMF@debug}
  {\let\MFX@debug\XMF@debug\errorcontextlines=\XMF@ecl\relax}
  {}
\endinput
```

Just a temporary hack, or maybe it could become something more stable if the author of **marginfix** is not reachable.