# Combining lmodern and tipa

Tags: fonts, linguistics, latin-modern, tipa

When I use `tipa` and `lmodern` in the same document, I always get a couple of font substitution warnings. The document looks fine, though. Is there any way around this?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[]{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textesh
\end{document}
```

pdflatex output:

```
test.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined

test.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

**EDIT:**
See [Filtering font substitution warnings caused by the combination of lmodern and tipa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37098/9787) if latex crashes when you try Seamus' solution.

Comment: on a recent full MikTeX installation, which I presume is what you have from your other post I don't get any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leo Liu's answer says that you can safely ignore them. This answer is a complement to that answer. It tells you *how to safely ignore them*. (And it borrows heavily from Stefan Kottwitz's answer to an [earlier question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24250/suppress-the-log-file-lines-written-by-a-specific-package))

You can use the [`silence`](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) package to turn off warnings from the appropriate package. So

```
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Some font}
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Font shape}
```

should turn off those warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just tried this and it doesn't work. Very strange. I don't have time to work out why not just now…

Comment: Quoting from the `silence` manual: "In case of a `LaTeX Font' message, the Name of the package is latexfont by convention."

Comment: Didn't spot that. But the error is more fundamental: just the combination of the three packages fails to compile.

Comment: Yeah, I amended my question with the crash. (Should I ask a separate question for this?)

Comment: @user1080125 Your first question was very clear and straightforward, and the kind of question that others might have.  I think you should ask a new question about the interaction. That way my and Leo's answers to the original question will still be useful to others.

Comment: I don't think it is a good manner to suppress all these font warnings. They are useful and sometimes they show true problems (see my comment on my answer). If the warnings make the IDE stop, you can configure the IDE only.

Comment: @LeoLiu I agree that they sometimes point to real problems. But _in this case_ they dont. So turning them off _in this case_ seems harmless. And turning them off can be an advantage: you might otherwise not spot a _real_ warning message because you're used to skipping over these warnings in the log file.

Answer (score 10):

The warnings are harmless, and the substitutions will happen automatically.  If you want to get rid of the warning you could redefine the `\textipa` command and the `IPA` environments to always use Computer Modern as shown in the example below.  If you decide later to change to using e.g. `mathptmx` then you would need to change the definition of `\tiparmdefault` to use `ptm` instead of `cmr`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\newcommand\tiparmdefault{cmr} % needs to be ptm if using mathptmx
\renewcommand{\textipa}[1]{{\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{\tiparmdefault}\selectfont#1}}
\renewenvironment{IPA}{\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{\tiparmdefault}\selectfont}{}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\textesh HGTR}
\begin{IPA}
\textesh
\end{IPA}
```

Note that in your example, you used an IPA defined character without enclosing it in `\textipa` or an `IPA` environment.  Even with this solution, doing that will still give rise to the warning.

Answer (score 7):

You can ignore it safely.

Latin Modern fonts have no `T3` encoding support. Since Latin Modern families come from Computer Modern fonts, it will works fine combining LM fonts with CM IPA fonts in `T3` encoding.

Comment: Are there no cases where font substitution warnings are *not* harmless?

Comment: @erik: Indeed there are some. You are supposed to read the warnings and understand it. For fonts warnings, you should know what the fonts are. When you change the font encodings which are not supported, you probably get some warnings and wrong result. For example, use XeLaTeX with `fontspec` and `txfonts` together, the font `EU1/txr/m/n` (Times) is missing, then changed to `EU1/lmr/m/n` (Latin Modern): it is wrong result, and you should use a OpenType/TrueType Times font with help of `fontspec`, or change the text font encoding to `T1` sometimes.