# Filtering font substitution warnings caused by the combination of lmodern and tipa

Tags: fonts, warnings, linguistics, latin-modern, tipa

This question is a follow-up to [Combining lmodern and tipa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37073/9787): I tried to filter the harmless warnings that occur when using `tipa` with the Latin Modern font. Doing so crashes both `pdflatex` and regular `latex`.

I haven't tested this on any OS other than Windows yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[]{tipa}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{LaTeX Font Warning}
\begin{document}
\textipa{\textesh}
\end{document}
```

Log:

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\lmodern.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\tipa.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\ot1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.def")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\silence\silence.sty")
(C:\Users\removed\test.aux)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\ot1lmr.fd")
pdflatex: Windows API error     87: Falscher Parameter.
pdflatex: Data:       C:\removed\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb
```

Comment: I separated your log from the MWE, just to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like a bug in `silence.sty`; it doesn't show if we patch `\wrong@fontshape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\wrong@fontshape}{\@gobbletwo}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Font shape}
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Some font}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[]{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textipa{\textesh}
\end{document}
```

The `\@gobbletwo` command is what disturbs **silence** working. It won't have side effects, other than a spurious "on input line xx" in the `.sil` file (if it's created).

## Update

Version 1.4 of `silence.sty` (2011/12/06) fixes the problem.

Comment: Has someone mentioned this to the author of `silence`?

Comment: I just did that.