# How do I get an Uvular Trill <ʀ> IPA symbol?

Tags: characters, linguistics, tipa

I've tried looking at [a tutorial](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/events/lcc/tutorials/tipachart/tipachart.pdf) online, which tells me that ;R should produce the ʀ symbol that I want to represent an uvular trill, but this only seems to produce a normal capitalised R.

What do I need to get the trill symbol that I want?

(I have looked at the [comprehensive symbols list](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and the closest I can find there is \textscr, which is better, but not perfect)

Comment: As far as I can see, it's a "small capital R", which should be the correct symbol. The syntax ``\;R`` works inside `\textipa`: `\textipa{\;R}` or, outside it, `\textscr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said by `egreg`, quoting Unicode's CodeCharts:

> U+0280 LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL R
>
> - voiced uvular trill
> - Germanic, Old Norse
> - uppercase is 01A6 Ʀ

Tipa version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\string\textscr}: \textscr
\end{document}
```

> [image: tipa]

Wsuipa version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ipa}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\string\scr}: \scr
\end{document}
```

> [image: wsuipa]

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has added the standard `tipa` way as an answer, which is mentioned in the document you linked to and in egreg's comment. Since you seem to be doing phonetics to me (as opposed to someone who just wants to get this specific single character for unrelated reasons), I would suggest to use the standard way.

I'll provide two versions: One basic one, which uses the standard Computer Modern fonts, and one more advanced one (but more realistic imho) that uses the Latin Modern fonts, basically in the way that Alan Munn proposed in [Combining `lmodern` and `tipa`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37087/4012).

```
% Computer Modern version
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}
Text with \tipa\ can be inserted in two ways, either  with the command
\verb+\textipa{...}+ or with the environment \verb+\begin{IPA}...\end{IPA}+.
The output is really similar; the command is like inline math \(1+1=2\):
\textipa{[a\;Ra:]}.
The environment is probably intended for longer consecutive blocks of IPA, which
constitute a paragraph of their own:

\begin{IPA}
[a\;Ra:]
\end{IPA}

This is typeset, however, pretty much like ordinary text.
This is different from a lot of environments that get extra space before and after,
as e.g.\ block math:

\[
1+1=2
\]

And this is just to show that there's extra space after our block math. Also,
it's centered.
\end{document}
```

If you want to use Latin Modern, the preamble could look like this:

```
% Latin Modern version
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % encoding of your .tex source file
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern font, basically an improved Version of Computer Modern
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc} % font encoding in the pdf output

\usepackage[noenc]{tipa} % noenc because we've already used fontenc

% This is based on Alan Munn's excellent advice for tipa and lmodern
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37087/4012
\newcommand\tiparmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand{\textipa}[1]{{\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{\tiparmdefault}\selectfont#1}}
\renewenvironment{IPA}{\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{\tiparmdefault}\selectfont}{}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
```

The output of both versions looks extremely similar; here's a screenshot of the `lmodern` version:

[image: output]