# How do you write aspirated consonants?

Tags: unicode, linguistics

I am working on a linguistic topic and need to be able to describe [phones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_%28phonetics%29) with aspiration. As described in wikipedias article on [Aspirated consonants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant) there is a UTF8 character for the diacritic of aspiration, ʰ. But in latex it only appears as a question mark and it cannot be escaped with a slash. How do you write it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see three "correct" ways of doing this.

### Using pdfLaTeX

[`tipa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa), which is the standard package for IPA symbols, provides one solution for normal text mode and one to be used in the `tipa` macro/environment (even though they both work in the surroundings they're *not* intended for as well):

> Sometimes the input method is displayed in the form of *Input1: xxx,
>   Input2: yyy*. In such cases *Input1* indicates the one used in the normal
>   text environment and *Input2*, the one used in the IPA environment.

The entry for superscript h looks like this:

> [image: Input1: p\textsuperscript{h} Input2: p\super h]

(both quotes from the [`tipa` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tipa/tipaman.pdf))

```
\documentclass{article}

% Either use the following setup for the Latin Modern fonts, or simply use the following line:
%\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % encoding of your .tex source file
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern font, basically an improved Version of Computer Modern
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc} % font encoding in the pdf output

\usepackage[noenc]{tipa} % noenc because we've already used fontenc

% This is based on Alan Munn's excellent advice for tipa and lmodern
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37087/4012
\newcommand\tiparmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand{\textipa}[1]{{\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{\tiparmdefault}\selectfont#1}}
\renewenvironment{IPA}{\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{\tiparmdefault}\selectfont}{}

\begin{document}

[k\textsuperscript{h}]% (For normal text mode)

\textipa{[k\super h]}% (For the \textipa macro)

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### Using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

You can also stay away from `tipa` altogether and input the Unicode glyphs directly. This suggests compilation with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Since Computer Modern / Latin Modern don't have the Unicode glyph ⟨ʰ⟩, you need to use a font that does, e.g. Linux Libertine or [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/).

```
% compile with xelatex or lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%   \setmainfont{Junicode}
    \usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

[kʰ]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to use the package `tipa` and use the `\super` function to write the superscript h.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
     The aspirated phone [k\super h]
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: The resulting pdf]

Comment: Why not just use `k\textsuperscript{h}` *without* [`tipa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa)?

Comment: @Werner Both are "correct" in their specific cases, see my answer.

Comment: So, according to the `tipa` manual, this solution is not correct, but it works nonetheless.