# lmodern + tipa cause first instance of diacritic to break

Tags: fonts, linguistics, tipa, lmodern

When I load both `lmodern` and `tipa`, the first instance of an IPA symbol with a diacritic breaks. For example, this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\=\textschwa
\=\textepsilon
\'\textschwa
\'\textepsilon

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

It's always the first character that's split, regardless of which diacritic and what body you use. E.g., if I change it to

```
\=\textepsilon
\=\textschwa
\'\textschwa
\'\textepsilon
```

I get[image],

and if I change it to

```
\'\textschwa
\'\textepsilon
\=\textepsilon
\=\textschwa
```

it produces [image].

How do I change it so the first character gets its diacritic on top where it belongs?

---

<sub>Note that there is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37073/combining-lmodern-and-tipa) about `lmodern`and `tipa`, but it only tells us that they work fine together and don't produce problems (beyond some warnings.)</sub>

Comment: As a workaround you can also put a schwa in a box that you don't render at the start, then this schwa receives the T3 warning and clears the way for the following diacritics, i.e., `\newsavebox{\schwabox}\savebox{\schwabox}{\textschwa}%`. But @egreg's answer below is more robust, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get warnings, don't you? Precisely

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textschwa' on input line 8.
```

You avoid them (and the wrong accent), with `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tipa}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{lmr}{cmr}

\begin{document}

\=\textschwa
\=\textepsilon
\'\textschwa
\'\textepsilon

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.

Comment: In fact, I don't get any warnings. I'm using overleaf, with precisely what I have written. The only thing it's complaining about is: "BibTeX No data sources defined!" I'm still wondering why I don't get warnings about the font.

Comment: @sgf If you look at the Raw Log in Overleaf the warning is there. Overleaf hides this from you. Alternatively, just wrap the code in `\begin{IPA}...end{IPA}`.

Answer (score 7):

You are using `tipa` macros without being inside  `\textipa{}` or the `{IPA}` environment which is not how they were designed to be used.  To get your example to work properly you should simply wrap the examples in the correct environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tipa}


\begin{document}

\begin{IPA}
\=\textschwa
\=\textepsilon
\'\textschwa
\'\textepsilon
\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

[image]